# Merge two files using first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have two different files and I'd like to do a merge of their information using the first column.

File1.txt

```
A,info1,info2
234,info3,info4
CD,info5,info6
```

File2.txt

```
234,ccc,bb
CD,aaa,dd
```

Expected output.csv

```
A,info1,info2,,
234,info3,info4,ccc,bb
CD,info5,info6,aaa,dd
```

I tried with `awk` (not my script) `join` and `grep` but I didn't obtain the desired result.

```
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR {h[$1] = $2;next} BEGIN{ OFS = "\t"} {print $0,$2?h[$1]:"0"}' file1.txt prova2.txt
```

and

```
join -a 1 <(sort file1.txt) <( sort file2.txt) > output.csv
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the number of fields in both files are the same then you can use `-o auto` to fill-up the number of fields in each line based on the first line of each file (by default it fills the missing fields with the value of `-e` option which by default it's space character but you can change it to any *string* you want);

```
$ join -t, -a1 -o auto <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
234,info3,info4,ccc,bb
A,info1,info2,,
CD,info5,info6,aaa,dd
```

we also added `-t,` to specify the field separators for the input &ouptut files.
if you want to add lines which are only exist in file2, add `-a2` to the command.

above command is the shortened version of below command which we explicitly saying which fields to output:

```
join -t, -a1 -o0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

`-o #.k` prints the `k`<sup>th</sup> field from the file number `#`.
`-o 0` here outputs the un-pairable lines.

---

#### Or using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; na="" }
              { key=$1; sub(/[^,]*,/, "") }
NR==FNR       { file1[key]=$0; next }
(key in file1){ print key, file1[key], $0; delete file1[key] }

END{ for(key in file1) print key, file1[key], na, na }' file1 file2
```

In the `{ key=$1; sub(/[^,]*,/, "") }` action, we take a backup from the first column then with `sub()` we remove that column by striping line upto the first comma character, so the remaining content will be the value for that *key* for the later uses.